# How to get the bearer token using selenium python?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, bearer-token, insomnia

[How to get this bearer token in selenium ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFIgF.png)

When I am using an API client like Isomnia, I found that it can automatically get the bearer token after I have provided the cURL. However, when I am trying to get the bearer token with selenium, I found no such methods or attributes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: https://gist.github.com/rengler33/f8b9d3f26a518c08a414f6f86109863c

It turns out the stuff that I was looking for were stored inside
driver.get_log("performance").

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).